How to show that a function $f(x,y) = x^2-3xy+5y^2$ is coercive?
Definition. A continuous function $f(x)$, defined on $\mathbb{R^n}$, is coercive if: $$\lim_{||x||\xrightarrow[]{}\infty}f(x)=+\infty$$
Problem. Is the following solution is correct:
$f(x,y)=x^2-3xy+5y^2\\\hspace{1.3cm}
=x^2-3xy+(\frac{3}{2}y)^2+\frac{11}{4}y^2\\\hspace{1.3cm}
=(x-\frac{3}{2}y)^2+\frac{11}{4}y^2\\\hspace{1.3cm}
\geq\frac{11}{4}y^2 $
Since $\frac{11}{4}y^2\xrightarrow[]{}+\infty$, as $|y|\xrightarrow[]{}\infty$, can we conclude that $f(x,y)\xrightarrow[]{}+\infty$, as $||(x,y)||\xrightarrow[]{}\infty$ ?

If this solution is not correct: why exactly is it incorrect & what would be a correct approach?
If this solution is correct: why do we consider the function $\frac{11}{4}y^2$ on a plane rather than in space? Would its limit as $||(x,y)||\xrightarrow[]{}\infty$ be $+\infty$ in space? For example, if we move on the line $y=0$ in space, we get $\frac{11}{4}y^2=0$ for all values of $x$, instead of it infinitely increasing.

"Coercive" is a very strange word to use for this property....

You're right that the given inequality does not prove that the function grows along the $x$-axis; another argument would be needed for that.

That is not correct. Because for example  the sequence $(n,0)$ goes to infinity, while your inequality only says that $f(n,0)\geq 0$.

A better way to deal with that problem is to work on a general setting: Suppose that $(x_n,y_n)$ goes to infinity as $n\to\infty$. Then at least one of the sequences $(x_n)$, $(y_n)$ goes to infinity. So I would separate in cases, for example, suppose first $x_n\to\infty$ but $y_n$ is bounded, then prove that $f(x_n,y_n)$ go to infinity in this case, the same for the other cases... It is not difficult at all

No, it is not correct because one can have sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ such that $\|(x_n,y_n)\| \to \infty$, but $|y_n|$ is bounded. For example, $(n,0)$.
However, you can also write $f(x,y) = \frac{11}{20}x^2+\left(y\sqrt{5}-\frac{3 x}{2
   \sqrt{5}}\right)^2 \geq \frac{11}{20}x^2$. Together with $f(x,y)\geq \frac{11}4 y^2$, we have $$\frac{20}{11}f(x,y) + \frac 4{11}f(x,y)\geq x^2 + y^2 = \|(x,y)\|^2\\ \!\!\!\!\!\!\implies f(x,y)\geq \frac{11}{24}\|(x,y)\|^2\to\infty\text{ when } \|(x,y)\|\to\infty.$$

Note. I used Euclidean norm even though you don't specify it, but it works with any norm on $\mathbb R^2$ since all are equivalent.


No, this is not a correct solution (see below for a correct one).
What is wrong about it? Well, $\frac{11}{4}y^2$ DOES NOT have a limit as $\|(x,y)\|\to \infty$, because if you approach infinity along the $y$-axis, then the result is $\infty$, but if you approach along the $x$-axis, you get a limit of $0$. This shows that the limit (as a function of two variables) does not exist; it is not $0$, it is not $\infty$, or anything else. It just does not exist.


Method 1:
You just need a more careful bound. Note that for each $\epsilon>0$, we have
\begin{align}
|3xy|&=3\cdot \sqrt{\epsilon}x\cdot\frac{y}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\leq 3\cdot\frac{1}{2}\left[(\sqrt{\epsilon}x)^2+\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\right)^2\right]=\frac{3\epsilon}{2}x^2+\frac{3}{2\epsilon}y^2,
\end{align}
where in the middle I have used the simple inequality $|ab|\leq \frac{|a|^2}{2}+\frac{|b|^2}{2}$ (which is valid for all complex numbers $a,b$) with $a=\sqrt{\epsilon}x$ and $b=\frac{y}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$. With this in mind, we have
\begin{align}
f(x,y)&\geq x^2+5y^2-\left(\frac{3\epsilon}{2}x^2+\frac{3}{2\epsilon}y^2\right)\\
&=\left(1-\frac{3\epsilon}{2}\right)x^2+\left(5-\frac{3}{2\epsilon}\right)y^2.\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
The question now becomes whether we can choose $\epsilon>0$ in such a way that both coefficients are strictly positive. Note that if $\epsilon$ is very small then the coefficient of $x^2$ is just slightly under $1$, so for sure it is positive. However, making $\epsilon$ too small will mean the coefficient of $y^2$ becomes negative. Conversely, as $\epsilon\to \infty$, the coefficient of $x^2$ approaches $-\infty$ while the coefficient of $y^2$ approaches $5$ (from below) so in particular is positive.
The issue is whether we can balance these two regimes of $\epsilon$. Fortunately, we can: simply choose $\epsilon=\frac{1}{3}$. Then, we get
\begin{align}
f(x,y)&\geq \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}.
\end{align}
So, $f$ is indeed coercive (and in fact, such an inequality is the more common use of the term). In fact, looking back at $(*)$, we see that any value of $\epsilon$ such that $\frac{3}{10}<\epsilon<\frac{2}{3}$ will ensure both coefficients are positive.

Method 2: Spectral Theorem
Your $f$ is a quadratic form on $\Bbb{R}^2$, i.e if you define $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-3/2\\-3/2&5\end{pmatrix}$, then for all $X\in\Bbb{R}^2$, we have $f(X)=X^tAX$. This matrix $A$ is real and symmetric, so by the spectral theorem, it is orthogonally diagonalizable. A simple calculation shows that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
\begin{align}
\chi_A(\lambda)&=\lambda^2-6\lambda+\frac{11}{4},
\end{align}
which means the roots (i.e the eigenvalues) are $\lambda_1=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\lambda_2=\frac{11}{2}$, both of which are positive, so $A$ is positive-definite.
More explicitly, the spectral theorem tells us that $A=Q^tDQ$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$ and $D=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$. So, by changing to the variables $\begin{pmatrix}\xi\\\eta\end{pmatrix}=Q\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$, we have
\begin{align}
x^2-3xy+5y^2&=\lambda_1\xi^2+\lambda_2\eta^2,
\end{align}
and the RHS is certainly a positive-definite quadratic expression (if you want to find $Q$ explicitly, ie find the correct rotation of coordinates, then you have to find the eigenvectors of $A$).

Probably a simpler approach would be: Suppose $\|(x_n,y_n)\|\to\infty$. Then at least one of the sequences $(|x_n|)$ or $(|y_n|)$ goes to infinity. Indeed, if both of them were bounded, then there exists $M>0$ such that $|x_n|,|y_n|<M$, so $\|(x_n,y_n)\|<\sqrt{2M^2}$ which is a contradiction.
Suppose $|y_n|\to \infty$, then as you proved $f(x_n,y_n)\geq 11/4y_n^2\to\infty$.
Suppose $|y_n|$ is bounded. Then $|x_n|\to\infty$. Then $f(x_n,y_n)=(x_n-3/2y_n)^2+11/2y_n^2\geq(x_n-3/2y_n)^2\to\infty$.
And we are done.
